# Seguridad en angular 7, como puedo hacer que se salga automaticamente despues del tiempo de sesion del sistemas?

Tags: angular7

Tengo una aplicacion donde recibo la hora de inicio y finalización de una sesión del usuario, el detalle es que debo utilizar para que salga automáticamente si el usuario no hizo ni un click en la aplicación, quisiera saber cómo angular 7 maneja procesos background(por debajo).

---

Estoy intentando con este método:

```
start(minuto) {
    let i=1;         
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
     if(this.evaluarHoraSesion(localStorage.getItem('horaFinal')))
     {

        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        clearInterval(timer);
     }
     console.log('paso minutos:'+ i);
    }, 1000*60*minuto);     

  }
```

El detalle es que no me actualiza la página automáticamente.

Comment: A simple vista tu pregunta parece demasiado amplia, puedes decirnos que has mirado / intentado para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Lo más simple es que ante una consulta el servidor te diga que la sesión ya está cerrada y actuar en consecuencia. En definitiva, no es una responsabilidad del front end estar controlando el fin de la sesión del backend. Sería peor que por una desincronización el front end diga que la sesión está cerrada cuando en realidad todavía está abierta en el back.

Comment: Estimado estoy intentando con este metodo: